# How to use regular expression in Common Lisp to get everything in a string until the last occurence of "/"?

Tags: regex, common-lisp

Suppose I have this string:

"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html"

I would like to have a regular expression so that:

```
CL-USER> (some-regex "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html")
```

Would return:

```
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/"
```

If I used the same function again on the previous output:

```
CL-USER> (some-regex "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/")
```

It would again get everything until the last "/":

```
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/"
```

Preferably, using [cl-ppcre](http://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/).

Comment: Not knowing Common Lisp in specific, but isn't that in most, if not all, regex implementation, multi-occurrence match is greedy by default? So `^(.*/).*$` should give what you need in group 1.  In worst case, you can still do `^(.*/)[^/]*$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is returning not everything until the last, but everything to the second to last slash.  I guess that you don't want to include the trailing slash to make this more regular.  Then the regular expression might in simple cases be `(.*)/.*`.  However, this gets surprising when there is no path:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun shorten-uri-string (s)
           (aref (nth-value 1 (cl-ppcre:scan-to-strings "(.*)/.*" s)) 0))
SHORTEN-URI-STRING
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string
          "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html")
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http://www.gnu.org/software"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http://www.gnu.org"
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-string *)
"http:/"
```

I recommend treating URIs as a data structure, not as a string, by parsing it.  The parser also knows everything about allowed/disallowed characters in each part of the URI.

For example, parse it with `puri`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defun shorten-uri-path (uri)
           (let* ((puri (puri:parse-uri uri))
                  (new-puri (puri:copy-uri puri)))
             (when (puri:uri-parsed-path puri)
               (setf (puri:uri-parsed-path new-puri)
                     (butlast (puri:uri-parsed-path puri))))
             new-puri))
SHORTEN-URI-PATH
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path
          "http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html")
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/software>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/>
CL-USER> (shorten-uri-path *)
#<PURI:URI http://www.gnu.org/>
```

You can render a URI to a stream with `puri:render-uri`.  You can also explicitly deal with query and fragment.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to solve the same problem avoiding Regular Expressions and using the QURI library?  https://github.com/fukamachi/quri

Comment: Yes, of course, puri is just one possible choice.